# How to update submodules in a main repository after modifying individual repositories (Backend and Frontend) in a project?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, git, github

I am working on a project with separate repositories for Backend (cw3-backend) and Frontend (cw3-Frontend) alongside a main repository (cw3WebApp) that acts as a container for both. The BE team works on the cw3-backend repository, while the FE team handles the cw3-Frontend repository.

When we are ready to deploy the project, we need to update the main repository (cw3WebApp) to include the latest changes from both the Backend and Frontend repositories. I usually perform the following steps:

Pull changes from cw3-backend into the api folder in cw3WebApp.
Pull changes from cw3-Frontend into the ui folder in cw3WebApp.
However, after pulling changes into the main repository (cw3WebApp), the changes are not reflected in the respective api or ui folders. Instead, they seem to be merged into the root of cw3WebApp.

My concern is that we have an office server where we all work together, but on the last Friday, we changed our server configuration. As a result, I pushed all my changes into cw3-Backend and took a pull in cw3Webapp, doing the same for the Frontend.

Now, I am attempting to clone the cw3WebApp repository on the new server (as it's attached to our AWS pipeline). However, when I cloned it, the api folder and ui folder in cw3WebApp both have the origin set to cw3WebApp itself, instead of having cw3-Backend origin in the api folder and cw3-Frontend origin in the ui folder. As a result, I am unable to take pulls from these individual repositories.

I have attempted to remove the origin for all submodules and then add the correct origins for each repo. However, when I switch branches and try to push or pull something, I encounter overwritten errors for some files.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to properly clone cw3WebApp with the correct submodule origins, so I can continue working with the separate Backend and Frontend repositories.